# Making only part of an image a hot spot link

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I have a large image and only want a rectangle portion of it to be a hot spot link that goes "Home".  Here is my code that is not working.  Any help on what I am missing or have done wrong?  Thanks!

```
<div id="defaultPic" runat="server">
        <img src="Images/boardwise-home.jpg" alt="Boardwise Home" usemap="#map"  />
        <map name="map" id="boardwise-home">
            <area shape="rect" coords="32,23,32,105,275,105,275,23" href="~/default.aspx" 
      title="Boardwise Home" alt="Home" />      
</map>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get your URL rewritten here with the '~' you will need ot use something like this:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="32,23,275,105" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx")"  
  title="Home" alt="Home" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Your rectangle has too many coordinates.  Should just be topleft x,y and bottom right x,y  ( ie coords="32,23,32,105" )

Comment: Thanks for the help.  The following code ended up working for me.  I had to put a resolveURl in there because I was working with a Master Page.  

    <area shape="rect" coords="32,23,275,105" href="<%=      ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx") %>

Answer (score 1):

I think for `shape=rect` the `coords` should be four values, like for instance `coords="32,23,32,105"`